# WooCommerce receive a copy of the email's bill to a specific email address

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, html-email, hook-woocommerce

I'm surprised this option doesn't exist. I would like to be able to receive only an email when the final billing is send to the client.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'woocommerce_completed_order_email_bcc_copy', 10, 2);

function woocommerce_completed_order_email_bcc_copy( $headers, $email ) {
    if ($email == 'customer_completed_order') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: Your name <emailnam@domain.com>' . "\r\n"; //just repeat this line again to insert another email address in BCC
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: First your question is too vague and unclear… Also, where is your code attempt? In StackOverFlow we don't code it for you, we just help people, most of the time, 
 on their own provided code.

Comment: Sorry. With this filter the email receive any email from WC'S order. I would like the email address receive only the bill (the last email). I hope it helps.